# Perform function first and then gather index of array onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a slideshow where the current photo is listed below in a circle and the circle changes color based on the current photo shown. The user should then be able to click on on each "bubble" and go to the appropriate photo while the show continues from that point.

The problem I am having is that I cannot remove the class, and then gather the index of the bubble. I cannot figure out how to use two separate loops with $bubbles.onclick. I tried with alerts for testing and it only displayed the second alert.

On a separate note, I also cannot get the the last bubble to remove class. The clipIndex skips the last value of the array and resets without displaying an alert and the last bubble stays pink.

Any suggestions? Sorry if the post isn't clear or the code doesn't read well, this is my first post.

```
    <div id="slideShow">
        <img class="clip currentClip" src="img/index01.jpg">
        <img class="clip" src="img/index02.jpg">
        <img class="clip" src="img/index03.jpg">
        <img class="clip" src="img/index04.jpg">
        <div id="sliderBubble">
            <img class = "bubbles currentBubble" src="img/sBubblePink.png">
            <img class = "bubbles" src="img/sBubble.png">
            <img class = "bubbles" src="img/sBubble.png">
            <img class = "bubbles" src="img/sBubble.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
   .clip {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .currentClip {
    display: block;
    }
    #sliderBubble {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 580px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```
    var $clips = $(".clip"),
    clipIndex = 0,
    numClips = $clips.length,
    sliderSpeed = 4000,
    sliderEffect = 1000,
    $bubbles = $(".bubbles");


    fadeOutCurrent = function() {
        $($clips[clipIndex++ % numClips]).fadeOut(sliderEffect, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("currentClip");
        });
    },

    fadeInNext = function () {
        $($clips[clipIndex % numClips]).fadeIn(sliderEffect, function () {
            $(this).addClass("currentClip");
        });
    },

    setBubble = function() {
        $bubbles[clipIndex % numClips].src = "img/sBubblePink.png";
        $bubbles[(clipIndex % numClips) -1].src = "img/sBubble.png";
    },

    initSlider = function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            fadeOutCurrent();
            fadeInNext();
            setBubble();
        }, sliderSpeed);
    };

newClipIndex = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < numClips; i++) {
        // Insert Function here for removeclass current bubble onclick
        (function(clipIndex) {
            $bubbles[i].onclick = function() {
                alert(clipIndex);
                $($clips[clipIndex]).addClass("currentClip");
            }
        })(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: `$(this).index()` will return the index of the current element.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked great and alot easier than looping through the whole set a different time. I am still working on getting the bubbles lined up correctly, but hopefully I can get it